# How to merge multi csv files line by line python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I would expect the code to merge the output csv files line by line. It will write the first lines one after another, then the second lines one after another.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, os, glob
path = (r'E:\csvfile')
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li,axis=0,names=None)
frame.to_csv (r'E:\csvfile\exportC.csv', mode = 'w', index=False)
```

I tried the shorter code with different parameters. >

```
import pandas as pd, glob
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(r'E:\csvfile/*.csv')),axis=0)
df.to_csv (r'E:\csvfile\exportC.csv',mode = 'w', index=False)
```

file1.csv

```
0, 10,12
0,11,12
1,15,12
```

file2.csv

```
0, 2, 1
1,22, 1
3, 11, 1
```

file3.csv

```
0, 4, 6
9, 14, 13
5, 6, 2
```

The expected output.

```
0, 10,12
0, 2, 1
0, 4, 6
0,11,12
1,22, 1
9, 14, 13
1,15,12
3, 11, 1
5, 6, 2
```

Thank you from now.

Comment: I suspect that there is a mistake in the expected output. Shouldn't the second line be `0, 2, 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first concatenate your three individual dataframes `df1`, `df2` and `df3` and then use the `sort_index` pandas method to reorganize your dataframe based on the index number:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv(file1.csv)
df2=pd.read_csv(file2.csv)
df3=pd.read_csv(file3.csv)
df=pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0).sort_index()
```

This will return:

```
   0   1   2
0  0  10  12
0  0   2   1
0  0   4   6
1  0  11  12
1  1  22   1
1  9  14  13
2  1  15  12
2  3  11   1
2  5   6   2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It solved my problem but it does not write lines sequentially, it writes in a mixed way within itself. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dataframe for each CSV, and write a function that loops and appends rows. If the CSVs are big, you can read them in chunks.

```
while i < df_length:
  df = df.append(df1.iloc[[i],:]).append(df2.iloc[i,:]).append(df3.iloc[i,:])
  i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It solved my problem but it does not write lines sequentially, it writes in a mixed way within itself. Is there a solution for this?